# Parsing oddly constructed Json/Gson

Tags: json, gson

I'll keep it brief, I'm having a problem with some really badly laid out Json (from what I can tell anyway), I'm pulling back from a web service, I'm new to java/android/json so any help would be gratefully received, the structure of the Json is:

> ```
> > {"cursor":
> >         {"currentPageIndex":0,
> >         "estimatedResultCount":32,
> >                 "pages":{
> >                          "label":1,
> >                           "start":0},
> >         "responseDetails":null,
> >         "responseStatus":200}, "results":[
> >         {"accuracy":24140,
> >         "addressLines":
> >                 {"Address1":"A house number",
> >                 "Address2":"A Street",
> >                 "Address3":"A city",
> >                 "Address4":"A State",
> >                 "Address5":"A Country",
> >                 "Postcode":"123456"},
> >         "city":"A City",
> >         "country":"A Country",
> >         "ddUrl":"http://link1.com",
> >         "ddUrlFromHere":"http://link2.com",
> >         "ddUrlToHere":"http://link3.com",
> >         "lat":54.52909583,
> >         "lng":-0.45554611,
> >         "phoneNumbers":
> >                 {"number":"123456789",
> >                 "type":"work"},
> >         "region":"China",
> >         "staticMapUrl":"http://link4.com",
> >         "streetAddress":"A house number, A Street, A city, A State,
> > 123456",
> >         "title":"Ali Baba Carpets",
> >         "titleNoFormatting":"<strong>Ali Baba
> > Carpets</strong>",
> >         "url":"http://link5.com"}]}
> ```

I'm trying to parse it using:

```
import java.util.List;

public class ParseOffers {
    private List<results> results;

    public static class cursor {
        private int currentPageIndex;
        private int estimatedResultCount;
        private pages Pages;
        private String ResponseDetails;
        private int ResponseStatus;

        public class pages {
            private int label;
            private int start;
        }
    }

    public static class results {
        private int Accuracy;
        private addressLines AddressLines;
        private String city;
        private String country;
        private String ddUrl;
        private String ddUrlFromHere;
        private String ddUrlToHere;
        private double lat;
        private double lng;
        private phoneNumbers data;
        private String region;
        private String staticMapUrl;
        private String streetAddress;
        private String title;
        private String titleNoFormatting;
        private String url;

        public class addressLines {
            private String Address1;
            private String Address2;
            private String Address3;
            private String Address4;
            private String Address5;
            private String Postcode;
        }

        public class phoneNumbers {
            private String number;
            private String type;
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are you parsing it?  By hand or using standard libraries?  `org.json` package in the adroid sdk should be able to parse this kind of stuff: [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)

Comment: @Aleks G -- The OP said Gson is being used.  Apparently in databinding mode.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is simply that the Java data structure does not match the JSON, in a few different ways, including missing a field for cursor, and having field names that did not match the JSON element names.

Here is a minimally modified version of the Java data structure that matches the JSON.

```
public class ParseOffers
{
  private cursor cursor;
  private List<results> results;

  public static class cursor
  {
    private int currentPageIndex;
    private int estimatedResultCount;
    private pages pages;
    private String responseDetails;
    private int responseStatus;

    public class pages
    {
      private int label;
      private int start;
    }
  }

  public static class results
  {
    private int accuracy;
    private addressLines addressLines;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String ddUrl;
    private String ddUrlFromHere;
    private String ddUrlToHere;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;
    private phoneNumbers phoneNumbers;
    private String region;
    private String staticMapUrl;
    private String streetAddress;
    private String title;
    private String titleNoFormatting;
    private String url;

    public class addressLines
    {
      private String Address1;
      private String Address2;
      private String Address3;
      private String Address4;
      private String Address5;
      private String Postcode;
    }

    public class phoneNumbers
    {
      private String number;
      private String type;
    }

  }
}
```

While this Java data structure works, it still has oddities I'd change.

It's odd that some of the nested classes are static and some are not.  I'd change it to not have any nested classes.

It's odd that some of the class names exactly match the field (and JSON element) names.  I'd use more common naming conventions.  For example, I'd change the name of the "cursor" class to "Cursor".

Comment: Cheers for that.Bizarrely, there's no actual reason for the nested classes, I'm actually the DBA and wrote the web service (it uses the .Net json library to create it) but the 3rd party that are calling it requested that we format it that way.